Why is the plot not showing the horizontal shifting?
I am trying to plot two sinusoids where one is a horizontal shift of the other using this code.
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, xspace,tikz} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xtick={
        -6.28318, -4.7123889, -3.14159, -1.5708,
        1.5708, 3.14159, 4.7123889, 6.28318
    },
    xticklabels={
        $-2\pi$, $-\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $-\pi$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$,
        $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $2\pi$
    },
    axis lines = center,
    grid=both,minor tick num=1,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    tick align=inside,
        %legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},
        % anchor=north,legend columns=2},
        % legend entries={$\sin 2x$\\$\cos 2x$\\},
        domain=-2*pi:2*pi,
        samples=200,
        every axis y label/.style={rotate=0, black, at={(0.5,1.05)},},
        every axis x label/.style={rotate=0, black, at={(1.05,0.5)},},
        ]
\addplot[blue, thick, smooth] plot (\x, {3*sin(2*(\x r))-4}); 
\addplot[red, thick, smooth] plot (\x, {3*sin(2*(\x r)-3)-4}); 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Why is the translation not reflected in the graph? I must be missing something simple but I figure it out. Also, any improvements to this code will be appreciated!

Try with a number bigger than 3. You can see the shift e.g. for \addplot[red, thick, smooth] plot (\x, {3*sin(2*(\x r)-30)-4}); 

Ah, I see. It probably has something to do with degrees vs. radians. Is it treating \x as being measured in radians, but not the "-3"?

I think it should in fact be sin(2*\x -3 r) since you want the whole argument of sin to be treated as radians, right? Didn’t test though. You can also try the rad() or deg() functions.
